# How to use Bash to find files whose gid != a fixed uid?

Tags: bash, comparison, find

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but I haven't figured it out yet— how would you use Bash to find all files in a directory for which the file's gid is different than its uid? I tried...

```
find $dir -user $uid -group !=$uid
```

...and was unsurprised when it didn't work. I haven't ventured beyond single commands with Bash yet, but maybe it's time.

Comment: Your question describes files whose uids (whatever they are) differ from their gids, but your code sample suggests you're looking for files with a fixed uid and a gid that differs from it.

Comment: @Sean: Right you are— I couldn't figure out how to word that correctly and concisely in the title. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
find . \( -uid $UID -a ! -group $UID \) -type f -ls
```

Comment: Hmm is there a reason you replaced `find . -uid $UID ! -group $UID` version? Just curious! :)

Comment: It's better to explicitly grouping the conditions.

Comment: But doesn't previous one do that? Does seem to work for me, is there any failure case in particular? (not able to think of any off the top of my head)

Comment: @sputnik - Thanks! I was confused about how to use operators in bash. Do all operators outside of parentheses need to be escaped with \, but not operators inside parentheses? And is the `-a` in your parentheses an "and", or something else? Part of my confusion stems from the fact that I haven't found a good bash guide to work from, so I'm jumping around a lot between different sources.

Comment: @ivan: that has nothing to do with bash at all. `find` is doing all the work, including parsing the search expression. `man find` will provide you with quite a lot of information about the `find` utility, but it won't apply to any other utility. (Still, it's good to know.)